# Grafana Prometheus datasource not showing metrics even though metrics were exported

Tags: spring-boot, grafana, open-telemetry-collector

Spring Boot 3.2.0, JDK 17

Using Grafana Stack running in Docker

After abandoning a JavaAgent solution and implementing a manual instrumentation using the Spring Boot to push metrics and traces, I now see Prometheus export logs in the collector. However, I show nothing in the Prometheus metric query drop downs. Additionally, Prometheus doesn't show any targets. I am thinking this is fine since I am not scraping for metrics as the actuator is locked down by JWT.

```
14:13:04.035 [main] INFO  i.m.c.i.push.PushMeterRegistry - publishing metrics for OtlpMeterRegistry every 10s
```

Collector Logs:

```
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.threads.states{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: executor.active{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.committed{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.committed{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: executor.active{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: executor.queue.remaining{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.gc.live.data.size{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: executor.completed{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.buffer.memory.used{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.committed{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: spring.integration.channels{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.threads.states{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: rabbitmq.acknowledged{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.used{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.buffer.count{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: logback.events{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.committed{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: rabbitmq.rejected{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: tasks.scheduled.execution{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.committed{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.max{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.threads.live{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.classes.unloaded{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.memory.committed{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.classes.loaded{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.threads.peak{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: application.started.time{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: rabbitmq.not_acknowledged_published{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: rabbitmq.failed_to_publish{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: tomcat.sessions.rejected{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: jvm.gc.memory.promoted{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
debug prometheusexporter@v0.91.0/accumulator.go:79accumulating metric: disk.total{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
info MetricsExporter{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "logging", "resource metrics": 1, "metrics": 109, "data points": 109}
info ResourceMetrics #0
 Resource SchemaURL: 
 Resource attributes:
      -> telemetry.sdk.name: Str(io.micrometer)
      -> telemetry.sdk.language: Str(java)
      -> telemetry.sdk.version: Str(1.12.0)
      -> service.name: Str(host-validation)
```

collector:

```
exporters:
  logging:
    verbosity: detailed

  #Metrics to Prometheus
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    enable_open_metrics: true
    const_labels:
      label1: osint
  otlp/tempo:
    endpoint: tempo:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true
  loki:
    endpoint: "http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push"

# The Collector pipeline.
service:

  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [prometheus,logging]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp/tempo,logging]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [loki,logging]
```

[image]

[image]

On a side note, I can see spans in Tempo and logs in Loki.
I am seeing an exception on startup but it doesn't seem to effect anything:

```
java.lang.Throwable: null
    at io.opentelemetry.context.ContextStorageWrappers.addWrapper(ContextStorageWrappers.java:32)
    at io.opentelemetry.context.ContextStorage.addWrapper(ContextStorage.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.tracing.OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.otelCurrentTraceContext(OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.java:159)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
```

Answer (score 0):

The prometheus exporter is not intended to be used to push metrics.

Moved to exporting to Mimir using https://grafana.com/docs/mimir/latest/get-started/